# How to return multiple values while calling a seperate function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to return integer values between two numbers while calling a seperate function in main.
The seperate function just uses a for loop to increment the first input.

the function "Values" needs to output all numbers inbetween a and b.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Values(int number1, int number2);

int main()
{
    int x;
    int x1;
    int x2;
    
    cout << "Type 1,2,3 or 4" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    if (x == 1)
    {
        cout << "Type in two numbers" << endl;
        cin >> x1 >> x2;
        cout << "The numbers in between are" << Values(x1,x2) << endl;
    }
}

void Values(int number1, int number2)
{
    
    if (number1 < number2)
    {
        for (number1; number1<= number2; number1++)

            cout <<  number1;
        

    }


}
```

Comment: Q: How to return multiple values [from a] function?  A: 1) Pass the parameters by reference (e.g. `void Values(int *number1, int *number2)`, or 2) declare a class, populate it with the return values in your function, and return a class instance.

Comment: @fruitsalad330 Why is the first number incremented?

Comment: do you actually need the numbers, or just need to print them out? `Values` could return a `std::vector<int>` with all the numbers if you actually need them.

Comment: Just need to print them out

Comment: then `Values` doesn't need to return anything. Give it a `void` return type and print them out as you are in `Values`, and simply call `Values` from `main`.

Comment: If all you need is a string of all the numbers, why not use stringstream? for instance: `if (number1 < number2) { std:ostringstream os;
os << number1++;  for (number1; number <= number2; number1++) os << ", " << number1;
return os.str(); }`

Comment: @yano I've changed it to void however, I get an error `no operator matches these operands            operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << void`. I've edited the code in the question.

Comment: right, there's nothing to `cout` in `main` now, change `cout << "The numbers in between are" << Values(x1,x2) << endl;` --> `Values(x1,x2);`. And in `Values`, you may want to put a space and comma between each number of something, they're all going to get mashed together with what you've got now.

Comment: @yano ok it works now... thank you!